# Map HTML to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, html, json

I'm attempting map HTML into JSON with structure intact. Are there any libraries out there that do this or will I need to write my own?

```
 <div>
      <span>text</span>Text2
 </div>
```

into a json object like so:

```
{
  "type" : "div",
  "content" : [
    {
      "type" : "span",
      "content" : [
        "Text2"
      ]
    },
    "Text2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I doubt there are libraries specifically for this. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I would recommend that go for something that is already out there like Jade instead of JSON

Comment: It would probably be somewhat ugly, but I think you could treat your HTML as XML, use a parser, then build it into JSON.  Probably not the best approach, but an idea.

Comment: interesting idea, but why is it needed? HTML already is a feature rich markup language to accurately describe a web page. If you attempt to transpose _all_ the information that could be held (attributes etc) it's going to get complicated and you'll need to be quite good at writing parsers. But what purpose does it serve? Presumably you'll need to write something to deserialise it again afterwards back into HTML? Why not just store/transmit (or whatever processing you're planning to do) the original HTML? It's just text, after all.